# Solving $AX=B$ recursively where $X$ and $B$ are matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

It's possible to solve $Ax=b$ recursively where $x, b \in \Re^n$ are vectors and $A \in \Re^{m*n}$ where $m > n$, buy using Recursive Least Squares(RLS).

But what if $AX=B$ where $A \in \Re^{m*n}$ and $X, B \in \Re^{n*k}$ where $k > 1$ and $m > n$. How can I solve that recursively if $A, B$ are known?

Comment: If $m \neq n$, then $AX \in \Bbb{R}^{m * k}$ cannot equal $B$.  Perhaps you want $A \in \Bbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $X \in \Bbb{R}^{n \times k}$, and $B \in \Bbb{R}^{m \times k}$.

Comment: @EricTowers Yes. My bad! Sorry. I  hope you understand that it's a solvable linear system. :)

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that $B$ is in the image of the map "left-multiply by $A$"?  This is implicit in your first paragraph (typically, by requiring $A$ nonsingular).

Comment: @EricTowers Sorry. Do not undetstand what you talking about. Solving $X$ from $AX=B$ can be done with $X = A^{+}B$, but that's not the recursive way. It's pseudo inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that each column of $B$ obtains contributions only from the matching column of $X$, and, conversely, each column of $X$ only contributes to one column of $B$, so you have "number of columns of $B$" simultaneous uncoupled equations in your system.

So the matrix version of your problem appears to be number-of-columns-of-$B$ uncoupled parallel copies of the vector version you describe first.

Comment: You mean that I need to solve each column of $X$ and $B$ separately?

Comment: I'm saying that you *can* treat each column of $X$ and column of $B$ pair separately.

Comment: But will that be correct if I solve each column of $X$ and each column of $B$ with $A$?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson : As explained in the first paragraph, each column of $B$ receives contributions from only one column of $X$, so changing an entry in a different column of $X$ cannot alter agreement with $B$.  Similarly, each column of $X$ is "blind" to any column of $B$ except the matching column of $B$.

Comment: Ok. I interprenting that you telling me that I can use RLS to solve $AX=B$ by taking one column at the time.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson : Agree.  Absolutely.  100%.